# Is it possible to use deferred loading with Polymer app in Dartlang?

Tags: dart, dart-polymer

Since Dart 1.6 we have deferred lib loading ( http://news.dartlang.org/2014/08/dart-16-adds-support-for-deferred.html ) hence the question:

Is it possible to lazy load polymer component with new deferred loading feature and then add them dynamically to app with like that:

```
var newElem =  new Element.tag("elem-from-deferred-lib");
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Deferred loading doesn't work with Polymer yet.

See https://www.dartlang.org/docs/spec/deferred-loading.html#can-i-use-deferred-loading-with-polymer-dart-elements (next to last paragraph) and issue https://code.google.com/p/dart/issues/detail?id=17873